# Emacs Eshell alias is broken

Tags: eshell

Eshell:
My long-standing very simple "ll" alias has somehow stopped working:

```
$ eshell/which ll
ll is an alias, defined as "ls -l $*"
$ # correct
$ *grep -w ll ~/.eshell/alias
alias ll ls -l $*
$ # also correct
$ ll foo*
```

<when I hit Enter on that "ll foo*" line, instead of executing "ls -1 foo*" emacs is prompting me in the minibuffer with
a prompt of 'Define alias for "ll":'>

How did this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: And now here I am in a different eshell and the result of my "eshell/which" and my \*grep are identical to the above, but in this eshell when I hit Enter on "ll foo*" I get "ll: command not found".